# installing a copper pipe on exterior wall (but inside the house)

Tags: plumbing

I want to add a pot filler. The Stove on the exterior wall of the kitchen.The wall is (from the outside in): Brick, Styrofoam insulation, 1/2" drywall, 1/2" plaster (yes plaster/drywall mud or something).

So, My thought was to:

- (along the stud) remove the plaster
- drywall and possibility some the insulation
- install the pipe
- secure to stud
- spray form insulation?
- fill hole
- new install of backsplash for oven area.

Thoughts? I live in Canada so first obvious concern is the freezing of the pipes thing. Especially since a new tiled backsplash will go over on top.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the kitchen sink already a pot filler? Am I missing the purpose of this device?

Comment: I think so. Basically it's a faucet that sits behind your oven out of the wall. So you don't have to actually carry the pot to the sink and carry it back. Google image search. (can't link it now as I'm on my phone)

Comment: What a strange kitchen design you must have such that carrying a pot from the sink to the stove is so great a hassle that it seems worth the effort to perform all this work.

Comment: definitely a luxury item. https://www.google.ca/search?q=pot+filler+kitchen&rlz=1CASMAC_enCA627CA627&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=BKbbVJr9B8K4ggSxsYHgCQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1024&bih=657

Comment: How thick is the insulation, and how much do you need to remove?

Comment: @bib i don't know either. I think since the plaster is 1/2 think and the dry wall is 1/2" thick I don't think I'd have to remove that much. But if I had to remove some and put in really good insulation then I would do that too

Comment: Would you be able to bump out the wall a couple of inches? You could build out the wall and then sheetrock over it without disturbing any insulation.

Comment: that would be a lot more work though. And then the backsplash wouldn't be flush with the rest of the wall

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to install a counter mounted pot filler next to the stove. That way you can run the pipe straight down through the floor, avoiding any work on the wall behind the stove.

Comment: thanks but the not desirable option.